# SQL Server : error conversion of a varchar data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to run a SQL query however I'm getting an error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Code:

```
SELECT 
    ClientId,
    DatePassed,
    Lender
FROM 
    dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage
WHERE 
    DatePassed = '2011-04-28 00:00:00.000'
```

I have converted the data type as so

```
SELECT 
    ClientId,
    Convert (Date, DatePassed)
    Lender
FROM 
    dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage
WHERE 
    DatePassed = '2011-04-28 00:00:00.000'
```

This however is still giving me the same error

Column `DatePassed` is of type `datetime null`

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Its probably having trouble with your milliseconds.  Plus, doing `date =` in your query is not very effective.  Usually you'd want to do a range, like between midnight and midnight.

Comment: Hey Paqogomez I have tried the WHERE DatePassed Between '2011-04-28 00:00:00.000' and '2011-04-28 23:59:59.000' Im still getting the error

Comment: What about the milliseconds?

Comment: What happens when you just do `Between '2011-04-28 and '2011-04-29'`? By default that will give you a 24 hour range. You might also have problems with the `yyyy-mm-dd`. Try `mm-dd-yyyy` instead.

Comment: Paqogomez When i did the between statement I received the same error as befor. I have Tried the the dd-mm-yyyy that seems to work however doest bring back any data

Comment: Before you dive deep into the conversion stuff (Bertrand's link in the answer below is an excellent reference) make sure the data you have in the column you're trying to convert is solid. If you have trailing/leading characters or invalid data (non-numeric characters) in the column it may throw this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, you think the `where` clause is performed before the `convert()`.  But that is not necessarily how the query is run.  The only SQL statement that guarantees order of execution is `case` (and then not all the time).

You can try this:

```
SELECT ClientId,
       (case when isdate(DatePassed) = 1 then Convert (Date, DatePassed) end),
       Lender
FROM dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage
WHERE DatePassed = '2011-04-28 00:00:00.000';
```

EDIT:

Given that `DatePassed` is already in a date time format, then your error is highly unusual.  This is not a problem from the conversion of this column, because no `varchar` is involved.

The only thing I can think of is the constant.  Perhaps you have a strange setting for default dates and it is trying to get the 4th day of the 28th month.  If so, you can readily fix this by putting in an explicit conversion with a format:

```
SELECT ClientId,
       Convert(Date, DatePassed),
       Lender
FROM dbo.tbl_Profile_Mortgage
WHERE DatePassed = convert(date, '2011-04-28 00:00:00.000', 121);
```

Aaron Bertrand has a rather extended discussion of this issue in his [blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).  By the way, even though I recognize the problem that he mentions with the YYYY-MM-DD format, I still use that by default.  I consider it a bug that Microsoft has chosen not to recognize this ISO standard format (but just because I think it is a bug doesn't necessarily convince anyone else).

Comment: Also, avoid implicit conversion at all costs. It may not solve your problem but changing `DatePassed = '2011-04-28 00:00:00.000'` to  `DatePassed = CAST('2011-04-28 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)` is good practice.

Comment: Hey Gordon this still gives me the error `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

Answer (score 2):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not. I guess in your case, you're using a language setting that just plain doesn't work with that string literal you're using.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible.

In your concrete case - use this string in your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE DatePassed = '2011-04-28T00:00:00.000';
```

(*notice the literal `T` between the date and time portions*)